how to get list of special orders in shopify - graphql
I'm trying to retrieve all orders with having _special_order=true feature, the issue is i'm not sure what argument or tag should be used to retrieve list of special orders in graphql
here is what i tried:
 orders(query:"tag:special_order", sortKey: CREATED_AT, reverse: true, first: 5,) {
    pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
        }
        edges {
            cursor
            node {
                createdAt
                name
                id
                lineItems(first: 5) {
                    pageInfo {
                        hasNextPage
                    }
                    edges {
                        cursor
                        node {
                            variant {
                                title
                                inventoryQuantity
                            }
                            sku
                            title
                            quantity
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

i tried _special_order, specialOrder tags in the node, variants, and tried it in the query:"tag:special_order" none of them worked
i'm new with shopify, thank for your help, i tried to go through their documentation, but couldnt find any line for special orders
